# How do I write conditional code for added data to existing Fetch API call in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

So...long story short, I'm using an API that has 714 rows of data and unfortunately does not include image URls. There's just NO WAY I can enter a URL for every API row or each objet in the data array.

So I created a separate JS file that is an array of image URLs that I use to connect the exact API property name to the image url.

For example:

**External images.js**

```
const Images = {
  "Canis lupus familiaris": {
    image:'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/23/14/dalmatians-3210166_1280.jpg'
  }
}
```

**Live API:**

```
[
  {
    "science_name": "Canis lupus familiaris"
}
]
```

I know this is **ugly** but inside a map loop of the data, I have this code. :

```
 let animalList = this.state.dataResults.map((animal, id) => {
  return (
    <img id={id} src={Images[animal.science_name] && Images[animal.science_name].image} aria-hidden />
)
}
```

Is there a way to write conditional code in there to display a general picture for the data records missing an image???? Since I can't get to all 714?

Can I fit an OR statement in there to use a general image.

```
<img id={id} src={Images[animal.common_name] && Images[animal.common_name].image} || if(no image) then use this general image pic />
```

OR put an if statement somewhere in the return?

let animalList = this.state.dataResults.map((animal, id) => {
      return (

```
if (Images[plant.common_name].image === null) {
    return (or display) "general.img"
```

I'm freaking out because this is due in hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ternary operator

```
return (
    <img key={id} src={Images[animal.science_name] ? Images[animal.science_name].image : 'http://general.png'} aria-hidden />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Try:

```
return (
    <img id={id} src={Images[animal.science_name] && Images[animal.science_name].image || 'http://URL.for/missing.image'} aria-hidden />
)
```

Basically, what goes inside the `{}`s is a JavaScript expression. So all you need to do is to add a string after `||` so that if the preceding expression evaluates to a falsy value it gets used.

You can also do it in other ways, just as long as they are valid JavaScript expressions, for instance:

```
let defaultImage = {image: 'http://URL.for/missing.image'};
let animalList = this.state.dataResults.map((animal, id) => {
  return (
    <img id={id} src={(Images[animal.science_name] || defaultImage).image} aria-hidden />
  )
}
```